# How to open gallery first instead of opening activity view?

Tags: android

So I'm trying to find a way how to write the code that when I open the app it automatically first of all open the gallery and then when you choose the picture it appears on Main Activity. How to do that? Am I need another activity? Because now first of all it opens Main Activity view and only then you can click the button and choose what you wanna do.

Code for loading and showing picture:

```
 ocamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


    } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is important to be able edit photos.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant

    return;


}


@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        im.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable();
        bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
        if (picturePath != null && bmp != null) {
            int height = bmp.getHeight(), width = bmp.getWidth();

            if (height > 1280 && width > 960) {

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Why not just call your method inside onCreate method of your activity? The method should simply open the gallery

Comment: OMG yas! thank ya@Eenvincible

Comment: Let me make this an answer so you can accept it and maybe others mind find it helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your gallery code to run as the first thing, you can simply call the method inside onCreate of your activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

    //you can check permissions here

    //call the method here with code you use to open gallery
    pickImageFromGallery();
}

private pickImageFromGallery(){
   //your code to open gallery here
   Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

   startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
```

This will ensure your gallery is opened every time. You can optionally call the method inside `onResume()` because then you will be guaranteed that the code will run.

Good luck and I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Actually this is works. Just I don't know it's my fault or not that every time I want to choose a photo it asks a permission to open the gallery. And the funny fact is that first of all I open the gallery and only then I get toast message about the permission. Everything next works fine.